# Getting some values from JSON response

Tags: ios, swift

I need to decode a NSDictionary received as JSON response using Alamofire.

This is how am I getting the JSON response:

```
//to get JSON return value

                        if let result = response.result.value {
                            let JSON = result

                            print("Result:",JSON)



                        }
```

And this is the printed output from the response:

```
Result: {
    error = 0;
    id = "<null>";
    precio =     {
        p1 = 280;
        p10 = 60;
        p11 = 70;
        p12 = 70;
        p13 = 60;
        p14 = 75;
        p15 = 35;
        p16 = 35;
        p17 = 80;
        p18 = 75;
        p19 = 80;
        p2 = 230;
        p20 = 70;
        p21 = 55;
        p22 = 0;
        p23 = 65;
        p3 = 180;
        p4 = 150;
        p5 = 100;
        p6 = 75;
        p7 = 65;
        p8 = 65;
        p9 = 60;
    };
}
```

What I need is to get some of the values, like p12 and p15.

If it helps, I have created a class called PreciosTicket:

```
struct PreciosTicket:Decodable {


    let p1: String
    let p2: String
    let p3: String
    let p4: String
    let p5: String
    let p6: String
    let p7: String
    let p8: String
    let p9: String
    let p10: String
    let p11: String
    let p12: String
    let p13: String
    let p14: String
    let p15: String
    let p16: String
    let p17: String
    let p18: String
    let p19: String
    let p20: String
    let p21: String
    let p22: String
    let p23: String

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down-cast to a dictionary:

```swift
if let result = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject],
    let precio = result["precio"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    print(precio["p12"], precio["p15"])
}
```

Using [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) is a much better method.